# Hibernate didn't create table

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have 7 entity and I set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to crate-drop.when I run my web application this sentence would print for all tables

> create table table_name....

.
all table will create except one.
this is my comments entity that hibernate didn't create its table.

```
@Entity(name = "comments")
@Table(name = "COMMENTS")
public class Comments implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID",columnDefinition = "NUMBER")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "COM_SEQ",sequenceName = "COM_SEQ",allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator = "COM_SEQ")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "CONTENT",columnDefinition = "NCLOB")
    private String content;
    @Column(name = "date",columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR2(20)")
    private String date;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    public Person person;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOCTOR_ID")
    public Doctor doctor;
```

I didn't understand why this happened?

Comment: make `hbm2ddl`  property  equals  `update`. in your hibernate `cfg` file.

Comment: even if I change it to update table comments won't create.

Comment: I am not sure if that is the cause, but change `strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE`.

Comment: any log or error?

Comment: @parladneupane I understood the problem.Hibernate didn't show errors in creating a table, it just wrote create table ...I copied queries in cmd and realized what was the problem, so I fixed it.Can we see errors in console??